# Clarification on Azure Artifacts Retention Policy handling of large package version quantities

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

Facing an issue in the Azure Artifacts Retention Policy working

My question is like how actually the retention policy works ? I have more than 100 versions of a package, like If I Enable the retention policy on 30 versions for 60 days to save then how it will work ? like what about my remaining versions like I have already said that I have more than 100 versions. So how its going to work, either it will delete the oldest versions from the 100 versions or it will delete the new versions. Lit bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

Currently retention works as if it followed this algorithm:

1. For each distinct package name:

   1. Create a list of all versions of that package name in descending order of publish date/time
   2. Remove from the list the top M (in your case 30) entries
   3. Remove from the list all versions downloaded within N (in your case 60) days
   4. Delete the versions that remain in the list